# Get number of deleted pages in PostgreSQL table/index?

Tags: postgresql, index, table, data-pages

How can I get the number of deleted pages in a table or index?

My purpose in asking is to modify an index bloat query that otherwise doesn't take into account which pages are deleted (and therefore not as harmful "bloat").

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a deleted page in a table.  The only way to delete a table page is to truncate a group of empty pages off the end of the table (VACUUM can do this automatically if it happens to find such a situation), in which case the page is no longer there to be consider deleted. You can use [pg_freespacemap](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgfreespacemap.html) to see how many pages are empty or nearly empty.

For indexes, you can also use pg_freespacemap, but you might need to investigate for each index type what it means for a page to be deleted.  Empty-ish index pages can be in a variety of states, and it might be unclear how "harmful" each one is, it depends on what you consider harm.  For example btree pages can be unlinked from the tree such that new queries don't need to traverse them, but already in-flight queries might still have links to them in their private memory.  They are deleted but not available for reuse yet and will not show as free in pg_freespacemap--and can persist in that state for a very long time.

Comment: Thanks. By "harmful" I mean "makes queries slower."